# Storing pictures in detail view of a an app that's main interface is a table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

So I am making a very basic iOS app, in which I want to be able to pick a picture from the photo library, and save it in a VC that shows up when you select a cell from table view controller.

The code to store the picture I have is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *fullImage = (UIImage *) [info  
    objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [Data setCurrentKey:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    self.image = fullImage;

    [self makeObjects];
    NSString *key = [[NSDate date] description];
    [Data setNote:kDefaultText forKey:key];
    [Data setCurrentKey:key];
    [_objects insertObject:key atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] 
    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kDetailView sender:self];
}
```

And here's my code for retrieving the VC after selecting a particular cell:

```
- (void)setImageObject:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.tView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width,   
    self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 200);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    NSString *currentNote = [[Data getAllNotes] objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    UIImage *currentImage = [[Data getAllNotes]    
    objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if(![currentNote isEqualToString:kDefaultText]) {
        self.tView.text = currentNote;
        self.imageView.image = currentImage;
    }
    else {
        self.tView.text = @"";
    }
}
```

For some reason, even though the text in each note is being saved, the image is not saving. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if your code in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo will be executed after `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Anyways, since you're calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:kDetailView sender:self];` I assume you're using Storyboard. In this case I suggest using `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;` where you can setup your new view controller with any data.

Comment: We should probably see your `Data` class, especially the `setCurrentKey:` implementation.  In one case, you call this method with a `UIImage` instance; in another with an `NSString`.  I'm not sure, therefore, how your data model is constructed.  Seems a little unorthodox.